# Need Create this Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

I'm trying to create a trigger but it is giving error:
General error: 1442 Can't update table 'users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

My Trigger:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER freejoin AFTER INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE users set new.plan_expiry_date = '2014-12-01 00:00:00', new.time = '30';
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `before insert` trigger:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER freejoin BEFORE INSERT ON users
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set new.plan_expiry_date = '2014-12-01 00:00:00';
    set new.time = '30';
END //

DELIMITER ;
```